# Javascript error in Firefox when using ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, javascript, firefox, ajaxcontroltoolkit, microsoft-ajax

I have recently been building a website that utilizes the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and the AJAX Control Toolkit.  The standard AJAX controls such as UpdatePanel work without problem.  As soon as I add a CollapsiblePanelExtender control from the AJAXControlToolkit to the page I receive a Javascript error. (NOTE: this problem occurs on Firefox.  IE works without issue.)

```
this.dateTimeFormat is undefined
```

on the line

```
this._upperAbbrMonths = this._toUpperArray(this.dateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames);
```

in the function

```
function Sys$CultureInfo$_getAbbrMonthIndex(value) {
    if (!this._upperAbbrMonths) {
        this._upperAbbrMonths = this._toUpperArray(this.dateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames);
    }
    return Array.indexOf(this._upperAbbrMonths, this._toUpper(value));
}
```

I have done some in-depth Google searching on the subject and this function used to have an error in the pre-release versions of ASP.NET AJAX.  This problem was caused by the variable _upperAbbrMonths being incorrectly referenced as _upperMonths in the return statement.  Although the same function is causing an error for me, it appears to be the updated version that has the corrected code.

What is the best way to correct the problem?

And even if there is an easy way to fix the javascript how can that change be implemented since the script appears to be generated by the ASP.NET AJAX framework?

Comment: I have successfully used the CollapsiblePanelExtender on a site with no problems in IE or FireFox. Can you reduce your code to a minumum that illustrates the issue and post it here?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know people actually used that piece of junk, now that jQuery is backed by MS...My experiences with the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit were less than stellar...